# Get ExactTarget accessToken from Salesforce callout

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, api, rest

I am trying to obtain the exacttarget accessTokem from a HTTP POST to 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken

I always recieve this response -> {"message":"Unauthorized","errorcode":1,"documentation":""}

If I make the same request from a .net program I get the accessToken succesfully.

What could be the problem?

This is the code:

```
string tokenURL = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';
string JSON = '{"clientId" : "mhf9y.....","clientSecret" : "hPjP9TqKY...."}';

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(tokenURL);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setBody(JSON);
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
try {
    response = http.send(request);
}
Catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    System.debug('Callout error: ' + e);
}
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

I tried passing different headers like user-agent, content length etc.. but the result is the same.

Thank you.

Comment: The clientSecret should be kept secret. Be careful not to post actual credentials on this site.

Comment: i thinks its actually truncated...

Comment: it seems to be issue related to certificate or having the Salesforce URL added to remote connections...but since its accepting a .net application call...its little confusing here...

Comment: Yes thank you.. I deleted the clientSecret.. anyways It´s a test app.

Comment: Yes, I added the url remote connection. Also I tried this code in different instances of salesforce..

Comment: Ok, the problem was the ip whitelist in ET. Once I added the salesforce ips in this whitelist works like a charm.